# Use MessageData with InMemoryTestHarness

Tags: masstransit

I try to setup an integration test using the in memory test harness of MassTransit. Since my MyCommandConsumer receives big binary data via the MessageData abstraction I need to configure the repository:

```
var provider = new ServiceCollection()
  .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
  {
      // this does not work:
      cfg.UsingInMemory((context, conf) => conf.UseMessageData(repository));

      cfg.AddConsumer<MyCommandConsumer>();
      cfg.AddConsumerTestHarness<MyCommandConsumer>();
  })                              
  .BuildServiceProvider(true);
```

Unfortunately the code above does not work yielding an exception:

```
MassTransit.ConfigurationException: 'SetBusFactory' can be called only once.
```

How can I configure the InMemoryTestHarness to use a MessageData provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve the test harness, and then add a configuration event. This should be placed before the call to `Start` the harness:

```csharp
TestHarness = provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
TestHarness.OnConfigureInMemoryBus += configurator =>
{
    configurator.UseMessageData(repository);
};
```